# Browsing Internet Problem

Tags: wireless, networking, firefox, internet, google-chrome

I continuously have a problem with browsing internet on Dell laptop through WI-FI.

The problem occurs suddenly, Firefox and Chrome refuse to find a resource, the interesting part is the connection is ok, skype works, pings is ok.

**Inversigation:**

1. Restarting browsers doesn't help.
2. Disabling/Enabling WI-FI doesn't help.
3. Disabling/Enabling networking doesn't help.
4. Retrive resources by IP doesn't help.
5. Lowering MTU to 1400 doesn't help.
6. Downgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't help.
7. Logout/Login doesn't help.

**Temporary Solution:**

Only full restart helps. (Not logout/login, but switch off and switch on)

**Terrible consequences**:

This laptop belongs to my girlfriend, and she threatens me, and demands to install Windows. I cannot stay any longer. So far I don't know what is the solution. Please help me to solve it, I will provide you with any needed infomation, log, etc.

Comment: Have you checked the 'Additional Drivers' to see if you have the most up-to-date proprietary Wi-Fi drivers installed?

Comment: Otherwise, get her to spend the £70 on Windows...

Comment: @Ads20000, The list of "Additional drivers" is empty. To spent  £70 is not a feasible solution.

Comment: Well, tell her that's the only way she's getting Windows :P
What wireless card do you have? (You might need a tool called 'sysinfo' to find this one out)...

Comment: @Ads20000, yeah I found, Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 (rev 34)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a solution by now but for the sake of keeping ur gf in the light of a real os : **did u chk the logs (/var/log)** maybe theres a hint, u may try another browser too (**midori** eg) but if u say the connection is ok but the browsers dont work anymore, maybe theres smthng wrong with the **DNS**. we should find out what exactly happens when booting up that differs from simply restarting the network.
And : r u sure everything is ok on the other end (**router, static / dynamic ip , filters etc**) ?

good luck man, may the gnuforce keep overhand on that hardware (-: